# Windows 11, Focusrite Solo, Guitar Rig 6 — Noise while watching YouTube videos?

Tags: audio, youtube, windows-11

I'm using Focusrite Solo (3rd Gen, Firmware 1605, Driver: 4.65.5) with Guitar Rig 6.2.3 on my rather ok PC (Core i7 12700, 32 Gb RAM, Windows 11) and almost every time I start playing my guitar while watching a video on YouTube (Chrome 100.0.4896.127, 64-bit) or a few seconds later I start hearing unpleasant "scratching" noise even on "clean" Guitar Rig presets.

It sounds like if my guitar or headphones cable would be damaged. But if I close Guitar Rig the noise disappears, so it's definitely *not* the cable. I haven't had this problem on my older PC (Core i5 2500K, 8 Gb RAM, Windows 10) with the same Focusrite interface and Guitar Rig. Another strange thing is: I can't record this noise. All the recordings I made with Gutar Rig internal recorder are ok.

Any ideas how I could find the bit causing the problem and fix it?

**Update:** The problem is not browser dependent (tested with Chrome, Firefox and Edge) and btw. I'm using the standalone version of Guitar Rig, not the plugin.

Comment: Could it be buffer size? Also do you have multiple windows logins

Comment: The buffer size is 192 (by default), I never had any problems with it on my older, much slower PC.